# MYSWL database. Trying to display a table. res.length is undefind

Tags: javascript, for-loop, undefined

I am working on displaying a mysql data table and creating a function which displays my data. When I run this function I receive the following error.

```
     for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
                              ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

---

```
function viewProducts(){
    var query = 'SELECT id, product_name, department, price, stock_quantity  FROM products Where stock_quantity > 0';

    connection.query(query, function(err, res){
        console.log('Items for Sale');
        console.log('Id \t Name \t Department \t Price \t Quantity\n');

            for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
                console.log(
                    res[i].id + '\t' + res[i].product_name + '\t' + res[i].department + '\t' + 
                    res[i].price + '\t' + res[i].quantity + '\n');
            };
         runSearch();
    });

}
```

Comment: Could you add a question? Also, did you check for errors in `err`?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting an error, and you're not checking for it.

Add something like

```
if (err) throw new Error(err);
```

to the callback function to see what's going wrong.

Comment: I ran that as well and I receive this error. Error: Cannot enqueue Query after fatal error.

Answer (score 0):

whenever you're trying to implement any I/O operation always catch the error before continue the execution. like this:-

```
function viewProducts(){
    var query = 'SELECT id, product_name, department, price, stock_quantity  FROM 
 products Where stock_quantity > 0';
    connection.query(query, function(err, res){
     if(err) {
      console.log(err);
     } else {
         if(res.length > 0) {
// only get inside if response is there
        console.log('Items for Sale');
        console.log('Id \t Name \t Department \t Price \t Quantity\n');

            for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
                console.log(
                    res[i].id + '\t' + res[i].product_name + '\t' + res[i].department + 
 '\t' + 
                    res[i].price + '\t' + res[i].quantity + '\n');
            }
         runSearch();
      }
    });
 }
 }
```